# Passing Value while changing ViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, viewcontroller

I want to create a `float[][]` array in one ViewController, but also use it in an different Viewcontroller, so I have to pass it.

I made my own class, which creates and holds this array, but how do I pass this class-instance when switching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing value to one class to another there are many ways like

- create a global variable
- create a singleton class
- NSUserDefault
- Segue
- Properties

As per your requirement use any one from it